# Migration from SVN to GIT repository

Tags: ruby, git, svn, migration

I found this nice article to migrate from SVN to GIT repo:

http://www.troyhunt.com/2014/08/migrating-from-subversion-to-git-with.html

This method using Ruby's svn2git tool to migrate but I am not able to install svn2git due to below error:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'svn2git' (>= 0), here is why:
Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - no such name (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

Found below link to resolve above issue:

https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88#manual-solution-to-ssl-issue

But the solution is already present in current Ruby installation. What else can be the problem?

Ruby version- 2.3.0

Plaform: Windows 8

PS:I cannot use SubGit tool.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-and-Other-Systems-Migrating-to-Git#Subversion - this is the "official" way, something wrong with this approach?

Comment: I guess the author want to preserve tags and stuff... svn2git gem uses git-svn tool, but also imports tags, etc.

Comment: @1615903 I tried the official way first, but I was getting below errors.

'Initialized empty Git repository in C:/my_git_project1/.git/
r1 = 888a54bf8a3a15409d71ac96c01a72c25aeb90a3 (refs/remotes/origin/trunk)
W: +empty_dir: trunk/hybris_export_java
r4 = b797395a056d4da7c536c158acda1ef4a39b6260 (refs/remotes/origin/trunk)
      4 [main] perl 2184 child_info_fork::abort: unable to map C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\msys-svn_subr-1-0.dll, Win32 error 1114
open2: fork failed: Resource temporarily unavailable at /mingw64/share/perl5/site_perl/Git.pm line 411.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a proxy server issue! I was accessing internet via proxy.

Used the below command to solve the issue:

```
set http_proxy=username:password@hostname:port
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you have installed `git-svn` tool installed, besides `git-core`.

```
sudo apt-get install git-svn
```

After, make sure you have successfully installed `svn2git` gem.

```
gem install svn2git
```

From your error message, I assume you haven't done this successfully.

Comment: Thanks @Uzbekjon, but it was some other issue related to proxy. Thanks for your help!